# Query problem with group by - Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'prueba.worker_times.check_in' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
   public function builder()
    {
        return WorkerTime::query()
            ->select([
                'workers.id',
                'workers.name',
                'companies.name AS company_name',
            ])
            ->join('workers', 'workers.id', '=', 'worker_times.worker_id')
            ->join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'workers.company_id')
            ->where('companies.id', 1)
            ->groupByRaw('workers.id, DATE(worker_times.check_in)')
            ->orderBy('check_in_date', 'ASC');
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: If you have fixed it, please provide the answer as it can help people in the future. Stackoverflow is to have a great database of resources, which means we have a responsibility to provide the best information. Instead of seeing the site as an way to get help with only your question.

Answer (score 0):

When `SQL` runs in `only_full_group_by` mode. You need to have all your selects in the group by or use aggregated functions to select em.

A workaround could be to use `MIN()` to get one one of the values, be aware due to grouping on `id` column, `name` and `companies.name` can have multiple different values.

```
->select([
    'workers.id',
    DB::raw('min(workers.name'),
    DB::raw('min(companies.name) AS company_name'),
])
```